# Cannot Connect PostgreSql Except PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver, datagrip

I can connect to postgresql server with pgadmin but when i try with another applications i'm receiving an error. I tried datagrip and dbeaver so far and error says

```
FATAL: unsupported startup parameter: extra_float_digits.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: can you provide with more detail,  in datagrip are you typing everything correct?

Comment: It looks like configuration should be changed on PG server (conf.ini):
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits